# What resource URL should I use for SSO-based local sideloading of Excel add-in?

Tags: azure-active-directory, office-addins, excel-addins

I have an Excel add in that works perfectly with SSO for my published add in - but when I sideload locally, I get:

> err: Invalid application resource Url provided - Invalid resource Url
> specified in the manifest. code 13004

How do I know what resource Url to use when running locally?

Answer (score 1):

From your error message, the most common problem is that the Resource element (in the WebApplicationInfo element) has a domain that does not match the domain of the add-in. Although the protocol part of the Resource value should be "api" not "https"; all other parts of the domain name (including port, if any) should be the same as for the add-in.

[Error 13004](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins#13004)

[Validate an Office Add-in's manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest)

If this doesn't help resolve your issue, can you share any documentation that you followed when adding the Excel add-in, so I can gain a better understanding of your issue.